# Self-modifying C# (MSIL) code?

Tags: c#, code-generation, reflection.emit, ilgenerator

How can I dynamically modify MSIL code in-memory with C#/.NET?

And yes, I'm really looking to **replace existing** code that's already in memory on the fly.
Specifically, I'm **not**:

- Looking to only generate *new* code (via expression templates, ILGenerator, etc.)
- Trying to emit a new binary module in the hopes of loading it into memory later

Comment: As far as I am aware, this is not supported in .net IL. Why is this specific scenario required?

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance: I can't really discuss the project I'm working on, all I can say is that having this capability would help a lot.

Comment: @sheldo Given that Mehrdad is talking about a Virtual Machine Runtime, whose premise of an easily modifiable IL comes with the .NET territory, it is definitely possible. Additionally with `unsafe` and/or Marshalled invocations there is little one can not do.

Answer (score 2):

[.Net Profiling API](https://web.archive.org/web/20131128154720/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188743.aspx) seems promising.

Otherwise, I'm stumped.

Comment: It seems to require native code... is there no way to do it from managed code?